# Command work in terminal but doesn't work with node.js

Tags: node.js, 7zip

I try to unpack img file with 7z on Linux. In terminal it works fine:

```
7z x myimg.img
```

But when I try to do this from node.js script it fails:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

childProcess.exec('7z x myimg.img', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

I get this message:

> exec error: Error: Command failed: 7z x myimg.img
> ERROR: myimg.img
> Can not open the file as archive

If I run command `whereis 7z` I get the same path.

Comment: You want to extract and `.img` file? Are you sure the file actually contains an archive? Or perhaps you mixed up `x` with `a`?

Comment: @zokkker13 7z-full can to extract .img files. And it works in terminal.

Comment: You are right, that works just fine, good to know. Your script works perfectly fine with my machine. I'm wondering where that `sudo` comes from. Perhaps you don't have permissions to read the file. Can you exclude that?

Comment: @zokkker13 it's just typo. I tried different variants and copy the wrong message. My img file has all permissions. I've given them with `chmod 777 myimg.img`

Comment: What happens if you execute `ls myimg.img`? Perhaps something is off with the CWD?

Comment: @zokkker13 it works fine :(

Comment: Then I'm lacking any more ideas. Perhaps you could do the same in a docker container or upload the image somewhere. Like I've said, it works finde for me so I guess the code works find and the error message itself looks like it's something about 7z.